Strange physics response with dynamic joint simulating vacuum gripper
I have written a plugin for gazebo harmonic that uses a contact sensor to spawn a detachable joint. As you can see in the video, the mast we are attaching to flips out when contact is made (even though it is set to static and has a mass of 1,000,000 kg).
I suspected it had something to do with the fact that DetachableJoint doesn't support making a joint when they are in collision, but when I disabled collision before the joint was made, I still encountered the same issue.
Is there a way to disable contact so the joint can be made without things going haywire?
Other contact gripper implementations:
https://github.com/usnistgov/ARIAC/blob/ariac2023/ariac_plugins/src/vacuum_gripper_plugin.cpp
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/gz-sim9/src/systems/detachable_joint

